# Close my account please. Delete it

Tags: support, user-accounts

Is it possible to close my account since I was not able to close it in this meta site.  Please delete my account.

Comment: You have already scheduled it for deletion, and it will be deleted in approximately 24 hours (it can be a few hours more sometimes) unless you change your mind before then. A moderator deleting your account would just cause it to go through the same waiting period.